# LDAP filter for email adresses in a different domain

Tags: ldap

I have an AD domain, mycompany.com.

Every account has an @mycompany.com email address, but there are also a few with emails in different domains; in those cases the account will have an @mycomapny.com address and a @somethingelse.com address, where @somethingelse.com could be any domain.

How do I construct an LDAP query to find account that have a non @mycompany.com address?  The LDAP attribute is proxyAddresses, and an account with multiple address will look something like:

```
proxyAddresses: SMTP:BOB@mycompany.com
proxyAddresses: smtp:BOB@randomdomain.org
proxyAddresses: X400:c=AU;a= ;p=MyCompany;o=Exchange;s=BOB;
```

If I filter for `(!(proxyAddresses=*mycompany.com))` then I will exclude all accounts that have a mycompany.com address, even if they have a different address associated as well.

How do I construct an LDAP query for "has a value for this attribute that does not end in mycompany.com"